# Adding methods to the "socket" object from the "websockets/ws" library

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

Any help with this is extremely appreciated!

**Background:** I am building a Node.js-backed website with WebSockets being part of it. I am currently using the [websockets/ws](https://github.com/websockets/ws) library.

**Desire:** I want to be able to create some "wrapper" sending functions so that in each of my socket message handlers to make it easier to maintain that functionality, should I ever choose to change it. Here is some example code of what I am currently doing:

```
const wss = new ws.Server({
    perMessageDeflate: false,
    path: '/ws',
    server: httpServer,
    verifyClient: function() { /* doing stuff here for client verification */}
});

wss.on('connection', function onConnect(socket, request) {
    // Using Lodash to extend the socket object to add the methods I need.
    _.assignIn(socket, {
        sendOk: function sendOk(message) {
            return socket.send(JSON.stringify({
                ok: true,
                msg: message
            }));
        },
        sendErr: function sendErr(message) {
            return socket.send(JSON.stringify({
                ok: false,
                msg: message
            }));
        }
    });

    socket.on('message', function onIncomingMessage(message) {
        try {
            let jsonMessage = JSON.parse(message);

            console.log('Successfully parsed incoming WebSocket message.');

            return this.sendOk('Thanks for the update!');
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.error('Error when parsing incoming WebSocket message.');

            return this.sendErr('Your incoming message was not a JSON string.');
        }
    });
});
```

**Problems:** With this approach, I am extending the "socket" object each time that a new user connects to the socket (after the initial handshake), which can cause so many problems (e.g. a user could connect and send a message before Lodash can complete the object extensions; the server will run into performance issues because that extension is an expensive operation; etc.). I need to be able to find a way to do this when the server is started, so that all incoming sockets will already contain the methods that I need before the WebSocket server has started listening for incoming connections.

Comment: You should use socket.io.

Comment: @SLaks Socket.io / Engine.io both have known performance issues, as well as additional library functionalities that I don't need. The "websocket/ws" library has everything I need and the performance I would expect. I am simply trying to add some minor functionality to this awesome library.

Comment: _"e.g. a user could connect and send a message before Lodash can complete the object extensions"_. Node.js is single-threaded, an incoming message can't preempt Lodash. _"the server will run into performance issues because that extension is an expensive operation"_. Why do you need Lodash anyway? Just assign to `socket.sendOk`. Or add your additional methods to [`WebSocket.prototype`](https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/master/lib/WebSocket.js).

Comment: Unless you're dealing with _extreme_ levels of load, the performance will be fine.  Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @robertklep => Even though that is likely true, I always assume every function call within JavaScript (yes, even library functions within Lodash) to be async. That is why I made that statement.

While I know I can use native JavaScript methods to accomplish the same thing, I usually find it safer to use Lodash because I got so used to it within the browser and its beauty there.

Comment: @th3n3wguy that's not the case :)

Comment: @SLaks => You're probably correct that I am "over-engineering" this, but I just wanted to make sure that there wasn't a way that I am missing that would allow for me to extend the socket when the server is started (without modifying the prototype), rather than on every single connection. I see now that this is something that I will have to do because modifying the prototype of another library is a terrible idea, since you have I have no control over it.

Comment: @th3n3wguy: async is not an implementation detail.  Asynchrony can only happen between the end of your synchronous code and a callback; it is fundamentally impossible for some other event to be inserting during your function calls.

Comment: @SLaks => While you are correct in that statement, I always forget the "gotchas" on certain methods being async vs synchronous in JavaScript (for example, Array.ForEach() vs for()), so just tend to go with "assume all function calls are async" mentality. Not always the best because situations like this come up, but it has saved me lots of headaches in the past. :)

Comment: @th3n3wguy: That's still completely false.  Asynchrony does not work like that; it is impossible for you to call an async method and not realize it (unless your code doesn't work at all).

Comment: @SLaks => That is not 100% true either, but we are getting off-topic. As I stated in my previous comment, most users coming from other programming languages think that the "for" loop is synchronous in JavaScript, like it is in almost every other language. In JavaScript, it is an async method (see examples as to why you can't do a console.log() inside of a for loop and see what you expected to see).

Thank you for all of the discussion. It was extremely helpful. :)

Comment: @th3n3wguy: No; the `for` keyword and the `forEach` method are _not_ async.  Are you actually talking about block scope?

Comment: @SLaks => Good point, and yes, that's what I was referring to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Problems: With this approach, I am extending the "socket" object each time that a new user connects to the socket (after the initial handshake), which can cause so many problems (e.g. a user could connect and send a message before Lodash can complete the object extensions;

This is not true.  Lodash object extensions are synchronous and Javascript is single threaded.  So, there is no opportunity for you to process an event after the `connection` event, but before you have the object extensions in place.  Can't happen.

> the server will run into performance issues because that extension is an expensive operation; etc.). I need to be able to find a way to do this when the server is started, so that all incoming sockets will already contain the methods that I need before the WebSocket server has started listening for incoming connections.

The extension is not an expensive operation.  It's just assigning a couple properties to an object.  It would be very, very difficult for that to be at all related to a server performance-related bottleneck.

If you really, really wanted to avoid assigning a couple properties on each new connection, you could modify the prototype of whatever your webSocket library was using.  You'd probably have to examine the source of that library to determine what the prototype is and whether you can modify it.  Personally, I find that more fragile than what you are doing now because that prototype is likely not a documented aspect of the interface.

It is a perfectly reasonable thing to extend a foreign object (an object whose constructor you don't directly call) by adding properties to it like you are doing.  That is probably safer (from a long term maintenance point of view) than adding things to the prototype unless the documentation for your object specifically documents adding things to the prototype.  It's even possible that the object doesn't even use a prototype (like I said, you'd have to look in the code to see if it does and if it's accessible to you).

Comment: This is exactly what I was expecting. You can see my response to the "sync vs async" in the comments to @robertklep of my post above. I figured that extending the object wasn't that expensive of an operation, but if someone knew how to extend the object at server-creation-time instead of at user-connection-time (I know, horrible wording there), then I would assume it would provide better performance. Thanks for re-instating what I was already feeling was the right choice.